# how to read file from local storage?

Tags: react-native

I am uploading image to device's local storage (Android), task is doing with success , now 
I am facing issues when I try to read the file from the local storage , it pops up errors
saying that :

> invariation Violation object are not valid React child

here is my code to upload the image :

```
let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
RNFetchBlob.fs.exists(dirs.PictureDir + "/myfolder")
    .then((exist) => {
            //console.log(`file ${exist ? '' : 'not'} exists`);
            if (!exist) {
                try {
                    const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
                    /
                    RNFetchBlob.fs.mkdir(dirs.PictureDir + "/myfolder")
                        .then(() => {
                                let base64Str = data;
                                fs.writeFile(dirs.PictureDir + "/myfolder/" + imageName, base64Str, 'base64')
                                    .then(() => {
                                        RNFetchBlob.fs.scanFile([{
                                            path: dirs.PictureDir + "/myfolder/",
                                            mime: 'jpeg/jpg'
                                        }]);
                                    }).catch(() => {
                                        alert("error");
                                    })
```

here is the path to my image

> const path =
>   dirs.PictureDir+"/myfolder/1718179779c718ba84098b90f6061816fba9f.jpg"

and here my code to access that image , could you please help

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">

        <View style={styles.containerWithMargin} >
        {RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(path, 'base64') .then( (data) =>
             <Avatar
             medium
             onPress={this.onSelectPostImage.bind(this)}
             source={{uri : data}}
           />
        )}

        </View>
```

Answer (score 2):

`RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile` returns a promise, anything asynchronous should be in `ComponentDidMount` and from there you can use `setState` to set `imageUrl` for example, then in jsx you will have something like this

```
<View style={styles.containerWithMargin} >
{imageUrl && 
   <Avatar
         medium
         onPress={this.onSelectPostImage.bind(this)}
         source={{uri : imageUrl}}
       />
}
</View
```